# Show 4 input file fields on my node add image page

Tags: 7, forms, media

I have a content type with an image field; the user can insert a maximum of 4 images. I need both the node add and edit form to show 4 input file elements, not only 1.

Answer (score 4):

When you add a field there is an option to set number of items. You can set the number to 4 and you would have 4 input elements on the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get fancy and your server supports it, you can use the [Plupload integration module](http://drupal.org/project/plupload).